# Safari: Caret duplicating itself in text input?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, safari

I'm currently experiencing some weird behaviour with the caret in Safari. When moving the caret after having something typed, it'll change its position as expected, but leave a duplicate behind. (See attached GIF).

[image: A visual representation of the bug]

This is in a React environment and I have so far only experienced it in a fixed Modal.

The code is nothing extraordinary, so this is probably some sort of browser bug:

```
<div
  className={classNames('xxx-input', !!this.state.error && 'error')}
  style={this.props.style}
>
  {this.props.label &&
  this.props.label.length > 0 && (
    <span className="label">{this.props.label}</span>
  )}
  <div className={'xxx-input-elements'}>
    <input
      className="xxx-input-field"
      value={this.props.value}
      placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
      onChange={this.props.onChange}
      type={this.props.type}
      disabled={this.props.disabled}
      style={this.props.inputStyle}
      {...props}
    />
  </div>
  <div className="error-label">
    {this.state.error || this.props.errorText}
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.xxx-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;

  .xxx-input-elements {
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid $xxx-input-border-color;
    display: flex;
    height: 36px;
    width: 100%;

    span {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .xxx-input-field {
      background-color: $xxx-input-background-color;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      height: 100%;
      outline: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```